# I am unable to open React native android app , android build is getting failed (app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac)

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments

I am unable to open React native android app after uninstall tipsi-stripe and @stripe/stripe-react-native library installed , android build is getting failed and showing below errors.

Error -1 :
import com.reactnativestripesdk.StripeSdkPackage;
^
E:\mom\share-app\android\app\src\main\java\com\mom\Reminder.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.stp_card_form_back)
^
symbol:   variable stp_card_form_back

Error -2 :

List.java:125: error: cannot find symbol
new StripeSdkPackage(),
^
symbol:   class StripeSdkPackage
location: class PackageList
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Error -3 :

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to

```
compileSdkVersion 33
targetSdkVersion 33
```

as `react-native-stripe` minimum requirements are

[image]

source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/stripe-react-native

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace `tipsi-stripe` with `react-native-stripe` and expect everything to work. You should review the [migration guide](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/docs/tipsi-stripe-migration-guide.md) for former `tipsi-stripe` users to see what is required.